# OnTouchEvent missing View parameter in Monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, touch-event

Why OnTouchEvent in Mono for Android doesn't have the View argument [OnTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) has in Android for Java? How can I get the view that's firing the event?

I'm trying to do something as the drag and zooming examples [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-4-setting-up-for-image-transformation/1785?tag=mantle_skin;content).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking at is `Activity.OnTouchEvent` which looks the same as it does in [Java](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). The example you're looking at is actually using the `OnTouchListener.onTouch` method, which in Mono For Android maps to `IOnTouchListener.OnTouch`. A basic class definition that implemented this inferface would look something like:

```
public class Touch : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see, so then the event needs to be assigned using SetOnTouchListener (http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Views.View.SetOnTouchListener%20%28Android.Views.View+IOnTouchListener%29)